# Allow XML file for Navigation to be shared across all sites

Tags: 2010, navigation, xml

I created a datasource that points to an XML file at the top level Sharepoint site. I then associated a treeview in a masterpage with the new datasource. It works fine on the home page but not on subsites. I gather that it has something to do with the XML file being stored at the top site and is not available to the other sites?

Can anybody recommend how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. It is to setup the xml file as a sitemap datasource and reference it in the Web.Config